# Update ng-model from controller

Tags: angularjs

Hopefully this is pretty simple, but my brain just isn't working at the moment...

I have a form like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="CN_PREF_NAME_J04">Name on Card:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="CN_PREF_NAME_J04" id="CN_PREF_NAME_J04" ng-model="formData.CN_PREF_NAME_J04"  />
        </div>
</div>
```

and I have a basic controller like this:

```
app.controller("CloseCallSpoke", function($scope){
    $scope.formData = angular.copy($scope.data);
}
```

This will automatically assign the entire formData object whatever is in my data object.

How can I just assign CN_PREF_NAME_J04?

i tried:

```
$scope.formData.CN_PREF_NAME_J04 = angular.copy($scope.data.CN_PREF_NAME_J04);
```

but I get "$scope.formData is undefined.

Please help.

Comment: As the answer below says, you haven't defined $scope.formData so trying to access properties of null is causing your problem the good ol' Null Pointer Exception (NPE) but stated differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$scope.formData = { CN_PREF_NAME_J04 : angular.copy($scope.data.CN_PREF_NAME_J04) };
```

That way `$scope.formData` is initialized with an object that has the `CN_PREF_NAME_J04` property you're looking for

Comment: Thank you!  Just what I needed.  Should have asked sooner!